# About Repository

Tags: repository

My Repository cannot be updated some item, please help me

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-br/projects/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-br/projects/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

you see ?

Answer (score 2):

If you go to the website you'll see that there's not sources for the oneiric distro:

http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-br/projects/ubuntu/dists/

Only precise, quantal and raring.

You have two options:

1. Remove that repository (I don't think you want to do this if you added it manually).
2. Edit the file that contains the repository and change all oneiric references to the actual distro you're using (which, by the way, you could tell in your question).

The file is in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ (not sure about the name) and you can edit it like this:

```
gksu gedit /tc/apt/sources.list.d/nameofthefile.list
```

There, change oneiric to your distro name.

If your distro happens to be oneiric, then you can't use this ppa as a source, you'll need to remove it from your sources, deleting the file which references it.